# How to delete buttons that was created programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, button

What would be the code to delete buttons that was created programmatically for this case for example:

```
for (m=0; m<f;m++ )
    {
        numerodeboton=partenumero+m+1;
        //NSLog(@"crear boton2, %i", numerodeboton);
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"boton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(notasCurso)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Botón %d", numerodeboton] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(espacioh+m*(h+d)-z + h/2, y + (l-1)*(v+d) + v/2, 1, 1);
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 30;
        button.clipsToBounds = YES;
        button.layer.borderColor=[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        button.layer.borderWidth=0.01f;
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.tag = numerodeboton;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.05*numerodeboton animations:^{
            button.frame = CGRectMake(espacioh+m*(h+d)-z, y + (l-1)*(v+d), h, v);
        }];
        [self.view addSubview:button];
    }
```

Let's say that I want to delete the button with `tag = 3`, what would be the code?

Comment: 1. `null` is not Objective-C - it is `nil`, and 2. That would just make the pointer to the button nil - the view would still have it. Plus how would you even set the button to `nil` if you're not saving references? You would have to get the subview based on its tag, but you don't mention that.

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee: I don't get your point at all

Comment: Well he's removed his comment, so this thread will look humorous to future viewers. On topic: I've posted an answer below - let me know if you have any questions pertaining to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `[[self.view viewWithTag:3] removeFromSuperview];` would get the button with tag 3 and then remove it. If you have multiple buttons with a tag of 3, just loop through them like so:

```
while (UIView *aView = [self.view viewWithTag:3]) {
    [aView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: No problem - glad to be able to help!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the safer way would be to use `[button removeFromSuperview]`, this will automatically release the inner view after that it has been retained by `addSubView:`.

Of course you'll need a way to retrieve the correct button, you could

- retrieve it `viewWithTag:`
- keep a `NSMutableArray` or a plain C array of them if you need more speed

Comment: Seeing as he's tagged them and is asking how to remove a button with a specific tag, `viewWithTag:` is by far the easiest method.